# Extra color in the bottom of collapsing toolbar in android

Tags: android

I created a collapsing toolbar from a tutorial and I've done everything he did. But there is a extra color right in the bottom of my image view. I tried many way but still have this problem. Is this a bug ? because my code is exactly same as tutorial but not working like that

[image]

Comment: Can you check your image view layout_height and scale_type

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir My image view height is 300dp and scale type is centerCrop . But I tried different size and scale type . all is the same

Comment: Have you try match_parent.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir The original image was very huge (more than 1500 pixel for height) and when I was choosing match parent it takes all of screen space . I resize it to less than 400 px and set to match parent and it worked :) thank you

Comment: Probably your collapsing toolbar height is wrap_content. So it take all of screen space. If you set collapsing height, the size of the image does not matter

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir You are right . I set collapsing toolbar height to 300dp and it worked well

Comment: Good luck for your android development